# Does MariaDB provides asymmetric key encryption

Tags: encryption, mariadb

I learned about the table encryption for MariaDB [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-at-rest-encryption/).

However, it seems the keys are located in a single file in a way an attacker could easily decrypt the data by having read access on the filesystem.

Assuming that it can be safer, I would like to encrypt database depending on one public key, and connect to the database through a private key file stored on my side.

Is that in any way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typical that encryption just moves the problem. It is possible to protect the key in storage but not easy or cheap and it is virtually impossible to protect it in RAM when being used by the DB.

Solutions to protecting the key in storage include moving it to an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) or another more secure and limited access system that provides the key to the DB over a secure link.

One advantage is that is the DB is obtained without the key it is secure, the problem is that the same access can also provide the key to the attacker. The work factor has increased and that may meet the security needs.

Comment: I understand the main problem, and what you are saying is it doesn't exist any way to log to a database with an asymetric key authentification?
I wanted to do not have to store the “private” key on a hard drive decrypted. This way, I am forced to do so because of the MariaDB need to know the authentication key. Am I wrong?

Comment: 1. The term “private” generally applies to one part of an asymmetric key pair (RSA/ES), for symmetric encryption (AES) the general term is "secret" key. 2. The key can be stored in an HSM or on another computer that is substantially more secure and limited to this one function. By substantially more secure I mean limited to only a very small number of administrators with 2-factor authentication, not connected to the Internet and securely connected to the DB server. This substantially increases the work factor.

Comment: You need to start with a security definition, what is being protected, from whom, what the value is and the capability level of the attacker.

Comment: I understood the problem but I wasn't able to find a better solution than “don't care of the key on the drive”. I think I will setup a restricted and logged access to a computer containing the secret key. Thank you very much. :)